# wrap s-expression in slime (emacs)

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime

Is there a short way to wrap an s-expression using slime?

Suppose i have finished some piece of code and I realize I need a variable (e.g. for efficiency reasons) and therefore want to wrap it with `let` or want to make it tail recursive and need to wrap it with `labels`, what is the fastest way to do this? Is there a shortcut?

IntelliJ (a Java IDE) allows things like:
`x > 3.if` + TAB 
yielding

```
if (x > 3) {

    }
```

So are there any "sexp-wrapping" shortcuts (postfix or prefix) in slime/emacs?

Comment: I don't know the answer; I just wanted to say that the title made me laugh :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "wrapping", but have you tried paredit mode?

Comment: @phils Ok, now I see it too ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bar represents the cursor.

### With paredit

There is a `wrap-round` command, bound to <kbd>M-(</kbd>. But when adding context to an expression, I generally do as follows:

```
|code
```

Open the parenthesis (the closing one is added automatically):

```
(|)code
```

... type ...

```
(let |)code
```

Call *paredit-forward-slurp-sexp* (<kbd>C-right</kbd>)

```
(let | code)
```

See also the [The Animated Guide to Paredit](http://danmidwood.com/content/2014/11/21/animated-paredit.html).

### Without paredit

```
|code
```

Call *mark-sexp* (<kbd>C-M-Space</kbd>), then kill the region; type and yank (paste) the text where you need it.

See also [Expressions with Balanced Parentheses](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expressions.html) (e.g. `forward-sexp`), available in Emacs.

Comment: paredit-wrap-sexp also works, as does paredit-wrap-round (bound to `M-(` by default).